# How do I align text and an image vertically inside a DIV?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically center an image and text. Here is the code I have in a wokring jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4a9XX/ as you can see the text is lower than the image how can I bring them to be level?

CSS

```
#display {
position:fixed !important;
bottom:0;
z-index:999;
background-color:#D41924;
width:100%;
padding:5px;
color:#FFF;
font-weight:bold;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="display"><img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2jd4due.gif" /> SOME TEXT </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use this (`vertical-align`):

```
​#display img, #display span {vertical-align: middle;}​'
```

And Enclose the text inside the `<span>` tags.

#### Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4a9XX/10/

Comment: You should be careful using `*`. It's great for quickly solving problems like this, but if you start using it everywhere you'll give yourself a real maintenance headache. It's usually better to say exactly what you mean. e.g. in this case: `#display img { vertical-align: middle; }`

Comment: As an aside - I find that images behave a lot more usefully if I set this rule at the top of my CSS: `img { vertical-align:middle; }`

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` may work in the browser you are using, but it is not in fact doing what you think it is. The `middle` property only works on inline elements, and centers it vertically in relation to neighboring inline elements. Not only that, but it only centers to the so-called _x-point_, which is sort where a lowercase x would be for that font

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy You are right. Its a quick fix... :) I will update the answerr... :)

Comment: it's ridiculous really. Rule of thumb: `vertical-align: middle` almost always doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried this in Chrome? It's not centered! See http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/

Comment: `vertical-align` works with images as long as they're `display:inline` (the default). I think most of the confusion comes from the bizarre behavior vertical align has with table cells (where you can specify it on the container).

Comment: @PraveenKumar Your jsfiddle link doesn't center properly - you might want to update it.

Comment: Incorrect. This is a common misconception for even those experienced with CSS. I'm using Chrome OSX 10.7, and it is **not** aligned. And `img` tags are actually rendered as `inline-block` not `inline`.

Comment: Here's some good reading on the subject: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/

Comment: Updated the fiddle to fit exact. Checked in IE 7, IE 8, IE 9, Chrome, FF, Mac OSX Chrome, Mac OSX FF... :)

Comment: So now you just hack it by putting in a `margin-top`? That's not going to work if the image were any bigger.

Comment: Yea... Its a hack for the current thing.

Comment: It's still misaligned in FF 13 OSX, and Opera

Comment: Not trying to give you a hard time, just trying to make the point that `vertical-align: center` does not do what you think it does. No matter how hard you try, `vertical-align:center` won't look perfect in every browser for what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Meanwhile I don't have a solution myself... =P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13499/discussion-between-musikanimal-and-praveen-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4a9XX/4/

Added a `span` tag to the text.

```
<div id="display"><img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2jd4due.gif" /> <span>SOME TEXT</span> </div>
```

Shift it using CSS `position: relative;`

```
#display span {
   position: relative;
   top: -3px;    
}
```

`#display span` selects a `span` tag that's a child of an element id `display`. Everything else is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

**Css**

```
   #display {
position:fixed !important;
bottom:0;
z-index:999;
background-color:#D41924;
width:100%;
padding:5px;
color:#FFF;
font-weight:bold;
}

img{
vertical-align:top;
}
p{
display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="display"><img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2jd4due.gif" /> <p>SOME TEXT </p></div>
```

because `img` **tag** is `inline-block` **element**

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/4a9XX/8/

Answer (score 0):

the `vertical-align` attribute should be applied on inner elements instead of the container. You can put your text in a `span` and apply `vertical-align` on both `span` and `img`:

```
​#display img, #display span {
    vertical-align:middle;
}​
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UYwJe/).